# Unable to understand error message in Spark Shell (Scala)

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.0.0 and trying to use the Spark Shell (Scala). But I am getting the error below, please can someone read the message for me and then tell me what it says

```
Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_55)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.

scala> val text = sc.textfile("/user/cloudera/test1")
<console>:12: error: value textfile is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkContext
val text = sc.textfile("/user/cloudera/test1")
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: @aaronman - I'm inclined to leave it open because he/she is trying to understand the error message.

Answer (score 4):

You are able to use Spark Context you just need to use the correct method. `textfile` is not a member of SparkContext, it says that in the message.  I think you want `textFile` :)